# becomeFirstResponder without invoking textViewDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, uitextview

Is there a standard way to ensure the keyboard appears on the screen and does not disappear? I've set my `textView` as the first responder, which ensures the keyboard displays, but I want text to appear in the `textView` (to let the user know what to type in the field) and when I become first responder I automatically invoke `textViewDidBeginEditing:` which is where I had initially set the text to `@""` after it had initially been set to `@"User instructions"`.

Comment: u have used multiple textfield or only one textview

Answer (score 1):

You can set Notification to detect when ever keyboard appears or disappears using NSNotificationCenter.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

In these methods you can handle what ever you want

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow
{

}
-(void)keyboardWillHide
{

}
```